# How should I add 120V service to an outbuilding?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I need to wire a small building off of my main service.  I will be running a few lights, a small TV, and a small fridge.  I want to run two 120V lines to it.  My question is can I run 10/2 using the ground as neutral/ground or do I need to run 10/3 2 hots neutral and ground.  I know that neutral and ground are essentially the same electrical connection inside the main panel.  And I really don't need to have the small building inspected.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How far away is the building? Do you anticipate needing any more electrical service there, especially 240V - tablesaws, welders, etc?

Comment: Why are you planning to use 10 AWG conductors?

Comment: what gauge should I run?

Comment: I will not need much power in the future this is a very small cabin

Comment: Neutral and Ground are NOT effectively the same connection in the main panel.  Ground should not connect to neutral.  Neutral is the 0 phase point between the two hots which are oppositely phased, and both hots and neutral connect to the main grid, while ground is an emergency release path for electricity to send it into the ground and does not connect to the grid.

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight in the house panel at home it looks that way.

Comment: @Joemaher The service neutral is bonded to ground, usually in the main service panel (though it can be done in a couple other places). Because of this, you'll sometimes see grounds and neutrals landed on the same bus bars in the panel.  This is acceptable, but only in the main panel where the neutral is bonded to ground.  Everywhere else in the system, neutral and ground are kept separate.

Comment: That makes sense thank you again for the great info.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use the ground as neutral. If you want two circuits, you'll have to use four conductors (hot, hot, neutral, ground).

If the run is short enough, you can use 12 AWG copper conductors instead of 10 AWG.  Depending on the loads, 12 AWG should be good for between 50-100 feet. If the run is longer than that, or you'll have larger loads in the garage. Then you might want to go up to 10 AWG copper, to reduce voltage drop.

You'll want to install a 20 ampere double pole GFCI circuit breaker, to protect the multiwire branch-circuit.  Even if you end up using larger conductors due to voltage drop, you'll still only install a 20 ampere breaker.

Other Points:

- You'll have to install a disconnect at the outbuilding.
- If you install a feeder rather than a branch-circuit, you'll have to install a grounding electrode system at the building, and bond it to the grounding conductor of the feeder.
- The feeder/branch-circuit will have to be wires/cable rated for outdoor/wet locations.
- If you think you might need more capacity in the future, you may want to install larger conductors and a secondary panel to accommodate future needs.

Comment: Effectively he's running a sub-panel to the out building then splitting from that so the 2 hots 1 neutral is a 220v feeder line being split out at the disconnect into 2 circuits.

Comment: 1) No disconnect is required and 2) no grounding electrode is required for a single multiwire branch circuit to a separate building.  3) is correct unless installed in PVC underground 4) is up to the OP

Comment: @CactusCake You can only feed a building with a single branch-circuit or feeder.  However, a multiwire branch-circuit is considered one branch-circuit.  So to have two 120V circuits, you'd install a single multiwire branch-circuit (hot, hot, neutral, ground).

Comment: @ArchonOSX 1) See 225.31 2) You're correct. 3) The interior of conduit in a wet location, is considered a wet location. 4) You're correct.

Comment: @Tester101 that's good to know. Is that allowed because they are on different phases?

Comment: Yes, the hots are the different legs of the service.  The neutral will only carry the unbalanced current between the two circuits.

Comment: @Tester101 see the exception at 225.36 1) 225.36 Suitable for Service Equipment. The disconnecting means specified in 225.31 shall be suitable for use as service equipment.

Exception: For garages and outbuildings on residential property, a snap switch or a set of 3-way or 4-way snap switches shall be permitted as the disconnecting means.  So, if the OP switches the receptacles and lights he is good.

Comment: @Tester101 3) you are correct I misread your post and was thinking you meant cable that is outdoor rated but if it is THWN rated wire the OP would be good. Actually, you edited your post to include wet locations. Your original just said outdoor.

Comment: @ArchonOSX the switches are the disconnect. I guess I should have been more specific about what is acceptable as a disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is can I run 10/2 using the ground as neutral/ground or do I need to run 10/3 2 hots neutral and ground?

You can use #12/3 for a multiwire circuit (a circuit with two hots and a neutral) unless the building is more than 100 feet or so. Then you might consider using #10/3 to compensate for voltage drop, but it still has to be on a 20 amp circuit breaker.

According to the National Electrical Code Table 210.21(B)(3) you cannot install 15 or 20 amp receptacles on a 30 amp circuit.

**You can NEVER use the ground as a neutral or vice verse in this type of circuit.**

Good luck and stay safe!